# sort_values versus sort giving different answers, but sort_values is the correct answer

Tags: python, pandas

I'm wondering what the difference between these two snippets of code could be?

```
New_Series = pd.Series(df['avg']).sort(axis=0, ascending=False, 
                                       kind='quicksort', na_position='last', 
                                       inplace=True)
New_Series = pd.Series(df['avg']).sort_values(axis=0, ascending=False, 
                                              kind='quicksort', na_position='last', 
                                              inplace=True)
```

`sort_values` returns the correct series, but `sort` returns `None`.

Is there a difference between these two that makes `sort` differently from `sort_values`?

Comment: `pd.Series.sort` is deprecated; use `pd.Series.sort_values`. You should get a warning when you use the first.

Answer (score 6):

Apart from the fact that sort is deprecated, it returns `None` when you use `inplace=True`

`sort_values` still returns the self updated dataframe is you use that argument as you can see in frame.py source code:

```
    if inplace:
        return self._update_inplace(new_data)
    else:
        return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self)
```

Comment: What do you mean deprecated?

Comment: sort function will be retired in a future version of pandas and only sort_values and sort_index will remain. So you are encouraged to not use sort anymore but the other twos instead.